# KnockoutJS now that jQuery Templates are on their way out

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js

Based around this [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Since the jQuery team has decided to keep jquery templates on hold I was wondering what the future of KnockoutJS will be and if I should consider to use backbone.js instead?

I'm in the planning stages right now to build a pretty large scale web app using ASP.NET MVC 4 and noticed that knockoutjs 1.3.0 is included in the project templates but do you think this will be in there for long?

Comment: Use whatever tools get the job done. Stop worrying about what is "approved" or "the hottest thing".

Comment: @Raynos - I'm not just worrying about the hottest thing. While still in the planning stages I'm looking to choose tools that will hinder iteration on a project due to it not being supported, bugs, compatibility, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout 1.3 (in RC right now) includes a native template engine.  This means that you can use Knockout with templates without referencing a template engine like jQuery.tmpl.

Here are a couple of posts to help describe it until the docs are ready:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-1-native-template.html

You would not be able to use jQuery.tmpl specific syntax (${variable}, {{each}}, etc.), but the control-flow bindings along with the standard bindings provide a mostly equivalent experience.

KO plans to support [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) (successor to jQuery templates) as well when its is stable.